# Testing a jQuery plugin in various browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, plugins, browser

When I have finally finished my jQuery plugin, is there an easy way to test it on as many browsers as possible?

It would be very tedious to install each one of the browsers versions and then perform a test. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jQuery, or JavaScript, or programming of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.browserstack.com/ works well for this. Its emulation runs in a Java applet. IE6 - IE9, Firefox 3+ etc. are supported. It's not super responsive, but better than http://browsershots.org/ which usually takes 30min for a single screenshot :)

The free plan only includes one hour of testing, so use your time well ...

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs like PHPStorm provide this. Otherwise I'm sure there are browser emulators on the web. Here's some examples:

- http://crossbrowsertesting.com/
- http://www.saucelabs.com
- http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/ads/qabrowsers.htm?gclid=CO_Xh_mXrKwCFcjb4Aodl01m5w